# 32 bit backup on 64 bit operating system

Tags: backup, 32-bit

Is it it possible to restore a backup made on 32 bit ubuntu on a 64 bit version? Like if you backup a 32 bit os and restore it on a 64 bit version.

Answer (score -1):

If you're talking about your files and documents, yes there is no problem

(There could be a problem in restoring a program which depends on a 32 bits library which is not in the 64 bits version, but otherwise I don't see any issue)

Comment: so if you use the built in backup program  everything is fine.